# New functions are not detected by vscode Haskell extension

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code, haskell-language-server

I have the following Visual Studio Code extensions for Haskell installed:

[image]

Let's say I create a new stack project:

```
stack new vscode-red-squiggly-test
```

And setup `Lib.hs` and `Main.hs` as follows:

[image]

This builds and runs just fine:

```
stack build
stack exec vscode-red-squiggly-test-exe
```

Now, if I add an item `xyz` to `Lib.hs` and reference it in `Main.hs`:

[image]

as you can see, a red squiggly show up under `xyz`.

Now, at this point, I can build and run the program just fine.

The hint when I hover over the squiggly is as follows:

[image]

If I close vscode, run `stack build`, and relaunch vscode via `code .`, the squiggly goes away.

So... is there a way to make the squiggly go away without having to relaunch vscode?

The suggested quick-fix is to add the following to the file:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -Wno-deferred-out-of-scope-variables #-}
```

However, I'd obviously like to avoid that as it turns off the nice feature of detecting truly undefined variables.

## Notes

- My Haskell environment is running within WSL on Windows.
- The vscode instance is running on Windows, initiated from within vscode via `code .`.

## Update

- I've submitted this as an [issue](https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/issues/2058).

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem, it turns out hls can defer your project. Would you share your debug output by enabling trace in the setting?

Comment: @JulyTree, yes I'd be happy to. Can you let me know how to enable tracing? :-)

Comment: Open setting in vscode and search `hasekll`, then you'll find a trace at the below, set it from off to messages. After that, restart your vscode, open output, there is debug message.

Comment: @JulyTree, OK, tracing is enabled. However, in 'OUTPUT' tab, I don't see any messages after I recreated the issue. Should I select a particular item from the menu displayed in this screenshot? https://i.imgur.com/ewU6Flh.png

Happy to setup a zoom with you if that's easier. :-)

Comment: @JulyTree, OK, I think I found the output:

https://pastebin.com/f2FxaLAr

That's what appears after I hover over the red squiggly.

Comment: See the list, I think `Haskell(vscode-red-squiggly-test)` is the one. By the way, maybe you can disable `Haskell HSX` temporarily, `Haskell language server` is enough as I know, they have conflicts probably.

Comment: @JulyTree, here's one more:

https://pastebin.com/9HW6f6We

That's what appears when I add I reference a definition that's newly added to `Lib`.

Comment: Log shows well, maybe you can disable `HSX` first?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235507/discussion-between-july-tree-and-dharmatech).

Comment: @dharmatech In Emacs, I sometimes have to restart LSP if I’ve modified a library and want those changes to propagate to the executable. Might this work with VSCode as well?

Comment: @bradrn, I can give that a whirl. How do you restart LSP?

Comment: @dharmatech Not sure, sorry… in Emacs I can run `lsp-restart-workspace`, but I don’t use VSCode so I’m not sure. Perhaps you could try closing and reopening the application if you haven’t already?

Comment: @bradm, Ah OK. Yes, restarting vscode does resolve the issue for that one squiggly. Creating a new definition however results in a new squiggly. :-) I'd have to restart after every definition.

Comment: @dharmatech Sadly, yes, it does seem that editing two components at once is a bit clunky. That being said, I find that generally I only work on one component at a time.

Answer (score 5):

This won't help resolve your problem, which is probably a Haskell Language server bug, but the quickest way to restart Haskell Language Server in VS Code is:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>
- Start typing until you find: `Haskell: Restart Haskell LSP Server`

This resolves a lot of HLS issues, and is unfortunately often neccessary, since HLs is not quite production-stable yet.

Happy Haskelling!

Comment: OK, I'm at a computer now. Yes, this suggestion works! However, I have to `stack build` before restarting LSP on order for it to work.

Comment: I've submitted an issue: https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/issues/2058

Comment: thanks for reporting the issue, the issue is quite similar to https://github.com/haskell/haskell-language-server/issues/1822

Comment: We have some issues with the setup of the project specially related with stack although we are working in improve it :-)